# How to replace each character like something, except those that have a certain character just before

Tags: oracle, replace

I have a text like this

```
'
-line1 //no space between line1 and 2
-line2

-line4

-line6
'
```

I want the text to become like this ( add break line before '-' only if there empty line before)

```
'-line1 //now empty line between line1 and 2

-line2

-line4

-line6
'
```

I'm thinking about using REGEXP_REPLACE.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (mytext, '-', chr(13) || '-')
```

This function add a line after every -. Is there an option to avoid replacing if there is an empty line before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace any newline which is preceded by a non-newline character and followed by a `-` with two newlines:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('-first line
-line2

-line4

-line6', '([^' || chr(10) || '])' || chr(10) || '-', '\1' || chr(10) || chr(10) || '-') AS out
FROM dual
```

Output:

```
-first line

-line2

-line4

-line6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8aac8ef0fcb8a1b8b38d96430e0e6ec7)

Comment: It's working on this example. But I don't know in advance what is the first line  is, If the first line 'the first line'. It doesn't work:

-the first lin1 \n the second line ...

Comment: Yes but they re not all ending with 1.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud sorry - I miscopied the regex. I've corrected the answer. It should have been a `\1`, not a `1` but because the line ended in `1` I didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

It seems that oracle regex does not support look-ahead and look-backs.
We could do your replace and then eliminate anywhere that there are 2 concescutive empty lines. We look for sequences of three newlines `\n` =  `Chr(13)` in a row, replacing them with two.

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE (
    REGEXP_REPLACE (
       mytext,'-', '\n-'),
    '\n\n\n','\n\n')
```

NB `\n\n\n` can also be written `\n{3}` .